# Multer throws error while uploading files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multer

When I don't concatenate new Date().toISOString and file.originalname in multer to upload file then it works perfectly. Files get uploaded. But if I concatenate to create unique file name then it says

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'rootDirectory\uploads\2020-10-22T13:28:21.741Zman2.jpg'
```

Even I tried storing value returned from new Date().toISOString and file.originalname and concatenate them and passed to callback function, it throws same error.

How to fix this?

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads");
  },
  filename: function f(req, file, cb) {
    // const originalname = file.originalname;
    // const date = new Date().toISOString();
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

`cb(null,Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, ""))`

Here is a complete way, if it helps

```js
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads')
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, ""))
      },
    })
```

Comment: Yeah,  this worked after removing space but I am wondering that there is no space in the path specified in the above code still why it is not working

Comment: There are two problems with your method of saving, first its always good to save files without ":"(colons) and "." (periods) which is generated by new Date().toISOString(), and second we are removing the space if in some case the system attaches space character to the filename, so it's just a double check to ensure the predictability of output